# Is there a better alternative to relocate cakephp3 config folder

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am using Cakephp3 and would like to know if there is a better alternative to relocating the config folder.

The issue rises from the fact that everytime I have to refresh the production app, i copy over the entire app from development to production and reconfigure the required settings in the config folder.

After some iterations of this process, I started to make a backup of the config folder and after copying the app, restore the config folder.

After some time even this started to get tedious, so I ended up hacking the cake files and folders.

- I relocated the config folder outside the root directory
- Created a symbolic link in the root directory poiting to the config directory outside the root directory.
- Updated the ROOT constant in config/paths.php to the real root folder
- In webroot/index.php redefined the bootstrap.php require location

So as long as long as I dont update the cakephp core, I can copy over the dev app to the prod app and all the config stays the same.

I would like to know if some one has a simpler approach.

Thanks

Comment: CakePHP has [environment configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html) built in. Why is this not sufficient?

Comment: I have seen resource you pointed out. However I think the problem is not with the configuration itself but wth multiple versions of it. In my case, the dev server has a different configuration compared to the production server. I was looking into some way to avoid overwriting the prod config with the dev config and then fixing it manually everytime I refreshed the application.

Comment: Create dev.ctp and prod.ctp files in the config folder (perhaps containing only the differences between the two), and conditionally load one or the other based on the server URL?

Answer (score 0):

After some research and reading carefully the comments in related bootstrap file, I found a solution for, well at least, my problem.

The problem basically was that I had to refresh the database, email, debug settings define in the app.php file, everytime I uploaded the app from my dev server to my prod server.

Reading the comments in the bootstrap file I found the comment which stated:

```
Load an environment local configuration file.
You can use a file like app_local.php to provide local overrides to your
shared configuration.
```

So this allows me to redefine the configurations defined in the app.php file. However I wanted this to me more dynamic, so I ended up creating an APP_INSTANCE_NAME constant in the bootstrap.php file of the webroot directory as follows

```
// /config/bootstrap.php
define('APP_INSTANCE_NAME', strtolower(gethostname()));
```

and later in the bootstrap file, i did the following:

```
Configure::load('app_' . APP_INSTANCE_NAME, 'default');
```

with this change, the configuration that gets loaded is based on the server hostname and I dont have to relocate the config folder. Hope this helps someone with cakephp3

Thanks to jason and greg's comments which motivated me to read the comments more carefully.